# How to submit a form with PHP?

Tags: php, form-submit

```
<form style="text-align:center;" id="paypalform" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
    <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
    <input type='hidden' name='business' value='payment@xxx.com'>
    <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='201001114262121'>
    <input type='hidden' name='amount' id="amount" value='1.00'>
    <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='CAD'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.xxx.com/paypal_process.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='invoice' value='82'>
    <input type='hidden' name='charset' value='utf-8'>
    <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
    <input type='hidden' name='no_note' value=''>
    <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://www.xxx.com/return.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='rm' value='82'>
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://www.xxx.com/index.html'>
</form>
```

Anyone knows?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you'll need to supply a whole lot more information here. You want to know how to submit to the Paypal API? Try here: https://developer.paypal.com/ - If you want some general PHP form info, there are loads and loads of demos and sample code online.

Comment: Maybe try adding a submit button?

Comment: Is this actually a question about PHP?  It seems like a question about HTML.

Comment: I want to submit the form at server side.

Comment: I hope these hidden fields are checked on server side, otherwise I could change the value to 0.00 and pay nothing :).

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
    {
        $params = array('http' => array(
                        'method' => 'POST',
                        'content' => $data
                    ));
        if($optional_headers != null)
        {
            $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
        }
        $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
        $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
        if (!$fp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
        }
        $response='';
        while (!feof($fp))
        {
            $response = $response.fgets($fp);
        }
        if ($response === false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
        }

        fclose($fp);
        return $response;
    }
    $host = 'http://mydomain.com';
    $url = 'http://mydomain.com/formHandler.php';
    $username = 'admin';
    $password = '123456';
    $data = array ('action' => 'login','lgname' => $username, 'lgpassword' => $password, 'format' => 'txt');
    $data = http_build_query($data);
    $reply = do_post_request($url, $data);
    echo "**********Response*********<pre>";
    echo var_dump($reply);
    #header('location:'.$host);
    #exit;

   } else {
       echo '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'"><input type="text" name="uname" /><br><input type="password" name="password" /><input type="submit" name="submit"></form>';
   }

 ?>
```

Try this

Comment: This answer and the question were... made for each other.

Comment: You can do this by CURL too : http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/sending-post-form-data-with-php-curl.html. Notes on this link

Answer (score 4):

If you're wanting this form to submit as soon as the page is loaded, you can add this to the bottom of the page if you're determined in using PHP to submit the form:

```
<?
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
                window.onload=function(){
                    document.forms['paypalform'].submit();
                }
       </script>";
?>
```

But that seems like a long way around it.  You could just write the javascript into the page... maybe I'm not sure what you're wanting to do, but I thought I'd throw this out.

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript you can submit the form inside PHP code like this:
(trick is in last line )

```
    $paypalURL = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    $paypalID = 'xyz-merchant@gmail.com';
    $form = "<form id='paypal' action='". $paypalURL."' method='post'>";
    $form .='<input type="hidden" name="business" value="'. $paypalID.'">';
    $form .='<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">';
    $itemDetail = "Detail goes here";
    $orderId = 4444;
    $totalAmountWithFee = 55;
    $form .='<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value=" '.$itemDetail.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="'.$orderId.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$totalAmountWithFee.'">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">';

    $form .="<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://localhost/public/cancel.php'> <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://localhost/success.php'>";
    $form.="<script type=\"text/javascript\"> document.forms['paypal'].submit();</script>";
    echo $form;
```

If someone has a good idea pls share.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit an HTML form from php with fsubmit PHP library https://github.com/randomsymbols/fsubmit

```
require_once 'fsubmit.php';
$html = '<form action="backend.aspx" method="post"><input type="text" name="question"></form>';
$form = new Fsubmit();
$form->url = 'http://the_url_must_contain_action_url_base'; // If form action is a relative link, then url is a required parameter, if form action is an absolute link, then this parameter can be omitted
$form->html = $html;
$form->params = ['question' => 'To code or not to code?', 'extra_question' => 'In what language?'];
$answer = $form->submit();
echo $answer['content'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can submit an HTML form from a PHP script with cURL or this library (that is based on cURL and simple html dom).