# How to submit a form with jquery "twice" (to form action and to an email)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

Let me explain better: my contact form sends a message as a new lead to Zoho CRM through a web form I generated there, but the great issue is that Zoho doesn't have an option to send me an email each time a new message (lead for approval) is sent from my website form, and I already missed a lot of quotes because of that.

So, I need to send an email to myself before submitting to the Zoho action url. I'm using jQuery validate plugin and have the following code in my js custom file:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#enviar').attr('disabled', 'disabled').attr('value', 'Aguarde...').css({
                opacity: '0.5',
                cursor: 'not-allowed'
            });
            $('.loader').customFadeIn('fast');
            $data = $(form).serialize(),
            $url = $(form).attr('action');
            $type = $(form).attr('method');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: $type,
                    url: $url,
                    data: $data,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('.loader').customFadeOut('fast');
                        $('.result-ajax-form').html(data).customFadeIn('fast');
                        $('#enviar').attr('value', 'Enviado').css({
                            opacity: '0.5'
                        });
                    }
                });
            }, 2000);
            return false;
```

Is there possible to use that same submitHandler function to handle a submit twice, one about the email I need to get and other for the form action url?

Comment: Rather than submitting directly to Zoho you could submit to a controller of sorts that would handle the Zoho submit as well as sending the email. I do not think submitting a form twice is the right design here

Comment: Great, but, how to do that? Any idea?

Comment: What backend language are you using?

Comment: PHP and website is WordPress based, but I handle the form manually, is not a plugin like contact form 7 or other else.

Comment: In that case submit the form to a php-page and handle the Zoho and email stuff in the php page.

Comment: So, I would have to use a sendmail routine and after that post the form data to zoho URL action. My doubt is how to post the form data once that data wasn't sent right after the form submission.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290025/how-to-submit-a-form-with-php, I am no php expert but you are better off posting a new question regarding the php part. As this questions is not tagged php.